# Go with Sublime 3 returns "go run: no go files listed"

Tags: go, sublimetext3

I have the following code from page one in the go tour:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
}
```

I saved the file in Sublime 3 with the name goTour and as the type go. When I build, I get:

```
go run: no go files listed
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
[cmd: go run C:\Users\new customer\Desktop\goTour]
[dir: C:\Users\new customer\Desktop]
[path: C:\Windows\System32\;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25"\bin;C:\devtools\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg;C:\Python34;C:\Go\bin]
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem or know how to solve it? I have installed go and gosublime.

Answer (score 10):

With main() function present in **.go** file within project's root, this works for me:

```
$ go run .
```

Answer (score 2):

Save the file as **tour.go** (mind the extension **.go**).

The command sublime tries to run is

```
go run C:\Users\new customer\Desktop\goTour
```

So it obviously does not have the right extension. The type in sublime does not really matter.

Answer (score 2):

**My Working Environment is Ubuntu 14.04.**

**My Working Directory Structure.**

$HOME/go/src -> for storing **tour.go** file

$HOME/go/bin -> for storing **tour** executable file

**I am hoping that you are in the present working "src" directory in your terminal.**
Then the command will be:

```
$ go run tour.go
```

If you want to run/execute compiled file then use this command:

```
$ $HOME/go/bin/tour
```

Answer (score 1):

In GoSublime, all I did was under the package directory with 9o prompt (#) and type:

```
 run
```

to run my code... this is what it looks like:

```
[ ~/Documents/software/go_tests/src/hello/ ] # run
    hello, world
[ `run` | done: 1.767649ms ]
```